# Rails Delayed Job Accessing value of background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer, observer-pattern, delayed-job

In my rails app, i have a timer ticking every second based on which different objects change their state. Thus, i decided to use Observer for this. However, when i ran the observer, i noticed it hung up my entire app until the timer completed. Thus, i was thinking of keeping the timer as a background job using delayed_job.

Now my query is that is there any way to fetch the value of the timer every second and use it for some operations in the controller? Example, if i had a set of images appearing at different times, i would ideally like to fetch this current time from the timer and if timing of the image and the current time matches, the images change. Hence, is it possible to fetch the value like this every second from the background process? If yes, can anyone please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your delayed job background process save the timer value and corresponding image link to a table. Then read in that value in your controller and act accordingly.

Comment: Ah ha, so if i understand u correctly, i can fetch that value and store it in a field in the table and this value dynamically changes every second right? As in the time keeps changes 1 to 2 and so on....for every second right?

Comment: Yes, if the delayed job runs every second you can just save Time.now into the database somewhere.

Comment: That sounds good.But what if the user were to enter the image link along with the time at which he wants it to be displayed, there would be a third field in which the current time is being fed dynamically. In that case, what is the value stored in that field once the user clicks 'Create' button on the form page ? As in once this object is created in the table, how do i edit the third field and continue to put the current time from the background process? Thanks for the help here!